# supressing NullPointerException in Mockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

DAOClass.makeDBConnection() method returns datasource configured (using lookup) in Application Server (Jboss). Need to implement junit test case for this scenario.

Using Mockito, tested the DAO method as follows. As it's not able to find the datasource(as expected), it's returning NullPointerException. How to handle  NullPointerException and return the connection which i am creating in below code? OR is there any other better unit test framework which handles this scenario ?

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DB:1433;DatabaseName=databasename", "userid", "password");

    when(DAOClass.makeDBConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mockito can't mock static method calls the way you have it; it effectively works by dynamically overriding all methods via a generated subclass (proxy).

You will need to write a wrapper class around static methods that you want to mock, otherwise refactor the code to avoid the static call, or use a tool such as PowerMock to rewrite your system's bytecode at runtime.

Comment: I am wondering, how static method calls is causing the issue ? even if i create an object of DAOClass and call makeDBConnection() method, it still throws NullPointerException.

Comment: when you say "even if i create an object of DAOClass and call makeDBConnection() method", is the method still static? Or did you change it?

Comment: Based on the naming convention, I assumed that you were calling `makeDBConnection` on the DAOClass class itself, not an instance, so I assumed it was static. Thus, your problem isn't about avoiding or suppressing the NullPointerException, it's reworking your test so you are setting expectations on object instances and inserting those object instances into your test.